# Expect spawn - send: spawn id exp4 not open

Tags: expect

I am trying to build an expect program that automatically gives passphrase to the crypt4gh program when decrypting a file. However, I get this "Expect spawn - send: spawn id exp4 not open" error, which many have encountered before while executing the spawn command.

This is the script that I have been trying to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn crypt4gh decrypt --sk /home/user/private_key.sec  < /home/user/file.txt.c4gh > /home/user/file.txt
expect "Passphrase for /home/user/private_key.sec: "
send "password\r"
```

After trying to execute it by`expect test.exp`, I get this error:

send: spawn id exp4 not open                                                                                                while executing                                                                                                     "send "password\r""                                                                                                   (file "test.exp" line 6)

If I leave out the last two parts that specify the input file `< /home/user/file.txt.c4g` and the output file `> /home/user/file.txt`, it works fine when I run the except script. Moreover, the decryption command (after spawn ) itself works when I run it in bash. I suspect this might have something to do with stdin (<) and stdout (>). Perhaps they are not compatible with spawn?

Comment: `<` and `>` are shell syntax and Expect does not support it.

Comment: as a workaround you can `spawn sh -c "crypt4gh decrypt --sk /home/user/private_key.sec < /home/user/file.txt.c4gh > /home/user/file.txt"`

Comment: Thank you @sexpect-ExpectforShells . I can confirm that this solved the issue. In addition, I needed to add `expect eof` after the send command for the decryption to output the correct file.

Comment: You can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more familiar with shell syntax.